# select multiple elements declared as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the example below how to say `a and b.show()` instead of  `$('.lorem, .ipsum').show();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = $('.lorem');
var b = $('.ipsum');
 $('.lorem, .ipsum').show();
//a and b.show();
});
```

```css
.lorem, .ipsum{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.add()`:

```
a.add(b).show();
```

The `.add()` method allows a selector string, or a jQuery object, one or more element node references, or an HTML string to be added to an existing jQuery object. Note that a *new* jQuery object is returned; the original `a` in the above example is unchanged.